# Why is the underscore OK inside of a `\cite` command?

Tags: citing, catcodes, underscore

The underscore character `_` has a category code of 8, because it has special meaning in TeX and a special role.

Including an underscore in the main body of a LaTeX document will generally cause a `Missing $ inserted` error because TeX expects this character to be in a math typesetting context.

I have noticed, however, that including the underscore character in the argument of a `\cite` command will not fail the compiler. For instance `\cite{forensic_engineering}` with a corresponding key in the `.bib` file will compile fine and throw no errors.

Could anyone explain why this is the case? I've checked the cite package [docs](https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/cite/cite.pdf) but it mentions nothing about special treatment of underscores.

Thanks in advance for your help.

## Edit

Passing an argument with underscore to a user defined control sequence does appear to generate a `! Missing $ inserted` error:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\test[1]{hello #1}
\begin{document}
\test{bla_bli}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Because using a category 8 token inside of `\csname` is fine.

Comment: Would you please point to where in Knuth's TeXbook or in the general documentation this is described? It seems quite arbitrary to me...

Comment: @Skillmon Please see edit to my original question. Using a category 8 token inside my own command will fail which seems to contradict your statement.

Comment: Not the most technical explanation but ... In your example, your macro `\test` expands to `hello bla_bli`. That is, the underscore "makes it to the document" during expansion, which produces an error. If you defined your macro as `\newcommand\test[1]{}`, there would be no problem in passing `_` to it, because the underscore would vanish during expansion. Similarly, if you use `\cite{forensic_engineering}`, a reference is inserted in the document (e.g. [1]) and the underscore is no longer relevant.

Comment: @user32882 -- `\cite` is not defined in basic TeX.  It has been added for LaTeX.  Therefore it will not be described in anything written by Knuth.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I was referring to the `\csname` construct. I would nonetheless have expected for this to be at least mentioned in the `\cite` documentation on CTAN as mentioned in my original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `_` for *typesetting* text is not allowed, because it has a special role in math formulas. It's much similar to the fact that `\alpha` in normal text raises errors (except in LuaTeX, but it's a different cup of tea).

When used in different situations, such as citation keys or labels, the underscore is usually safe.<sup>1</sup>

Why? The TeXnical reason is that citation keys and labels are wrapped up inside a `\csname...\endcsname` instruction, which disregards category code (other than 13) of the characters. However, the easier “rule” above, that is “typesetting versus nontypesetting” is perhaps simpler to remember.

<sub>**Footnote**</sub>

<sup><sup>1</sup> Exception: when a package such as `underscore` does nasty things in order to allow for using `_` in normal text for producing an underscore.</sup>

Comment: Hi, I tried to follow your answer but can't figure out how it works with arguments containing `_`. My understanding of both `\csname...\encsname` is that it lets us name control sequences using any categories (besides 13 I think). In that regard, it's clear but how do you make it work with arguments containing all characters; an underscore inside a label? Are those characters converted to a control sequence? Thanks